# No view scope in faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf-2

Why is there no `view` scope in `faces-config.xml`? How would I set a bean to view scope, if I am not using faces-config.xml?

I have used the following bean file:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class StatusBean2 implements Serializable  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7528998562821856315L;
    private EntityManager em;

    public StatusBean2() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("FreeBird");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                .getSession(true);
        int toIndex = 5;
       session.setAttribute("toIndex", toIndex);

    }
    public List<Status> getStatusList() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                .getSession(true);
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='"
                + user.getEmail() + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc",
                Status.class);
        List<Status> results = query.getResultList();
        Query query1 = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Friend f WHERE f.email='"
                + user.getEmail() + "'", Friend.class);
        List<Friend> results1 = query1.getResultList();
        Iterator<Friend> it = results1.listIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String email = it.next().getFriendEmail();
            Query query2 = em.createQuery(
                    "SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='" + email
                            + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc", Status.class);
            List<Status> results2 = query2.getResultList();
            results.addAll(results2);

        }
        Collections.sort(results);

        int toIndex = (int) session.getAttribute("toIndex");
        List<Status> subList = results.subList(0, toIndex);

        return subList;

    }
}
```

The exception that I am getting when I am using annotations is as follows:

```
Apr 16, 2013 8:41:23 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/Home.xhtml]
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.bean.StatusBean2
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:293)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:167)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:221)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:406)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 16, 2013 8:41:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/FreeBird_New2] threw exception
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.bean.StatusBean2
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:293)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:167)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:221)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:406)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: *"If I am not using faces-config.xml"* Why this question then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@ViewScoped` annotation on managed bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AViewScopedBean {
    //managed bean contents...
}
```

If you don't like the annotations configuration (really odd), you can just set the view scope on faces-config.xml

```xml
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>aViewScopedBean<managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>some.package.AViewScopedBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Note that this **only works** on JSF 2. Check that your *faces-config* file is configured to handle JSF 2.x version:

```xml
<!-- relevant part of faces-config.xml file for this Q/A -->
<faces-config ... version="2.1">
```

---

Edit based on your question update:

The error message is pretty straightforward:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: com.bean.StatusBean2

This means that your `com.bean.StatusBean2` must also implement the `Serializable` interface. From [`java.io.Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) documentation:

> When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not support the Serializable interface. In this case the `NotSerializableException` will be thrown and will identify the class of the non-serializable object. (this is the error you're getting)

You can learn more about Java Serialization here: [Java Serialization](http://www.javabeginner.com/uncategorized/java-serialization)

From your question: *is it necessary to implement serializable?*, BalusC already posted a good answer/explanation: [JSF backing bean should be serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3372687/1065197)

Comment: Can you please post the faces-config jsf file version?

Comment: is it necessary to implement serializable because I am getting an exception

Comment: @AmlanKarmakar could you please edit your question and add the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @AmlanKarmakar, yes `Serializable` is required, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16040752/516433) below.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the `xsd` listed in your `faces-config.xml` (for example: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd) should show you that `view` scope is an allowed managed bean scope:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="faces-config-managed-bean-scopeOrNoneType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>
        <![CDATA[[
        Defines the legal values for the <managed-bean-scope>
        element's body content, which includes all of the scopes
        normally used in a web application, plus the "none" value
        indicating that a created bean should not be stored into
        any scope.  Alternatively, an EL expression may be used
        as the value of this element.  The result of evaluating this
        expression must by of type java.util.Map.

        ]]>
      </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:restriction base="javaee:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="view|request|session|application|none|#\{.*\}"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

*Assuming jsf 2.0 or later*

***This is not a new answer per-se, just another way to find out for yourself that it is allowed***

**--------------- EDIT ----------------**

Check [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html):

> Note that the bean needs to implement Serializable as it will be
>   stored in the view map which is in turn stored in the session. Some
>   servletcontainer configurations will namely store sessions on disk
>   instead of in memory. This is also mandatory when you have configured
>   JSF view state saving method to client instead of (default) server.

To explain why view scope requires `Serializable`.

Comment: `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl` I am getting the above exception after I add Serializable.

Comment: @AmlanKarmakar, That would probably be because you inject a non-serializable variable into your serializable managed bean, thus making the bean _effectively_ not-serializable.  To get around this, you can follow the approach outlined in [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14183778/516433).

Comment: Could you show me an example, I am having problem to understand the concept of transient.

Comment: @AmlanKarmakar transient means that the value of the variable is left out when the object gets serialized.  which in turn means that the value of that variable will be null when the object gets de-serialized.  which effectively means you cannot safely inject that dependency.  instead you should prefer the lazy loading approach outlined in that BalusC answer.

Comment: @AmlanKarmakar all that is covered in the link about Java Serialization on my answer. Note that the links are there in order to be reviewed.